# How to identify the Sunspot Malware is present?

Tags: malware-removal

I just watched this malware do a man in the middle attack on one of my clients paying for a service using their credit card and cannot find any source to confirm it is in fact Sunspot so I can verify post removal process. No anti-viruses detect it!
http://www.net-security.org/malware_news.php?id=1719
Any ideas?

Comment: How did you "watch" it? Packet sniffing?

Comment: Try the System Sweeper boot disc....http://connect.microsoft.com/systemsweeper

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Comment: I watched the user complete the transaction they do on a monthly basis and when they did the post back another form popped exactly as described in the article. Claimed to be mastercard but image links were broken. The giveaway was it was asking for an ATM pin. I'll grab a screen shot next time.

Comment: Updated title and description to "Identify" as to more accurately define the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the two registry keys mentioned in the article you posted, this is where it launches from.

> Once installed, Sunspot is started either by "rundll32.exe" via

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

or via

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components.
```

> It uses CBT hooking to load its DLL into the browser (Internet Explorer/Firefox).

Or better yet use a browser it does not "hook", like [Chrome Browser](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/make/download.html?brand=CHKZ)

Comment: Yeh, I checked HKCU\RUN was clear and HKLM\Install Components had too many CLSIDs and folders distinguish.
What do you mean by hook?

Comment: "It uses CBT hooking to load its DLL into the browser (Internet Explorer/Firefox)." Its a term use to describe injecting a process or dll into another program or process, some are legitimate, some are malware.

Comment: You would have to look through all the install component keys for something that does not look legitimate in the right pane, use google when needed, I have only 24 installed components in my reg key. You will be looking for a dll or path to a dll that is not legitimate windows dll. Did you try the System Sweeper I recommended?

Comment: I used System Sweeper which successfully removed the malware.

Comment: I like that scanner boot cd, its a good one. Glad you got it removed....http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533